# Form with button adding new field to it

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I wonder what is the best way to create a dynamic form with Django.

Let's say there is a Training form which can embrace some Workouts. Number of Workouts is unspecified (1+). How to create such a form with a button adding new Workout to it?

EDIT:

My backend is written in Django/Python.
So far, my models looks as below:

```
class WorkoutForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 45)
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)

class TrainingForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 45)
    all_workouts = Workout.objects.all()
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    selected_workouts = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=[(o.id, o.name) for o in all_workouts])
```

But I want to change it to dynamic form with new Workout field added after clicking Add button.

Comment: You don't need django for this. You can just use simple jQuery.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Aren't they asking about formsets and particularely inline model formset ? adamura88, is Workout a related model in your case ? Please paste your model code.

Comment: @jpic Does it mean, what I answered doesn't help?

Comment: Well I'm not sure, validation depends on their data model.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help you?

```js
$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      // Make sure nothing happens.
    $(".master")
      .clone()                // Clone this
      .removeClass("master")  // Remove the master class
      .find("input").attr("name", "workout[]").end() // Change the input name
      .appendTo("form");      // Append it to the form.
  });
});
```

```css
label {display: block;}
.master {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label class="master">
    <strong></strong>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <a href="#" id="add">Add New</a>
  <label>
    <strong></strong>
    <input type="text" name="workout[]" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will also work, depending on your needs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="workouts">
    <div class="workout" id="workout1">
      <label>Workout:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="addWorkout" type="button">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  $("#addWorkout").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var last = $("#workouts").last().attr("id")
    template = "<div class='workout' id='workout" + parseInt(last[-1])+1 + "'><label>Workout:</label> <input type='text'>"
    $("#workouts").append(template);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but how to do it on Django side?

Comment: @adamura88 I can give you an Idea, basically you would need to write a functionality like a `add` function in the trainingform class that would call the workoutform class which would create the new field(I assume) and then  another `update` function which would update the number of workout fields